# Projection mapping as an external display for a computer

Tags: software-recommendation, projector

I'm using a projector to display the content of my computer, as one would do with a regular screen. Now I want to do the projection on several panels that have different orientations. Hence I'm looking for a projection mapping solution.

Is it possible to do projection mapping with the HDMI output of my computer as projected content? If it is, could you recommend me a tool to do so? So far, the projection mapping softwares I've found can only project content that is internal to the computer and defined in advance, such as solid colors, video or pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Youre likely going to have a tough time accomplishing this without the right toolset.

Im not aware of any opensource projection mapping software that could accurately output a signal to a projector or series of projectors to accomplish a decent map.

Christie (you can visit their website and search youtube for examples) is the only projection mapping software / hardware solution Ive toyed with... back when I had two Christie HD10K rigs.

But good projection mapping typically requires at least 4 projectors all tied into the same video engine. You need up down left and right, otherwise shadows will be a major issue.

Typically, 6 or 8 units are used on a single simple object for wrap around effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Resolume Arena`, at [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=resolume%20arena%20projection%20mapping) you can get tons tutorials

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your answer so that it will help more people? A link to the software and a useful tutorial, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to do live projection using [Mad Mapper](https://madmapper.com/), but fundamentally I think you won't get a usable result.
Sending a single HDMI output from your computer to a projector, and then projecting this across multiple different panels means the pixel resolution on the individual panels is going to be much lower.
Unless you have some sort of mammoth video card with multiple outputs, I'm not sure this would generate usable, readable output for the purpose you propose.